# Release management in TFS on QA Server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2015

How can I automate the release management to QA Server in Team Foundation Server? Right now I release thorough Visual Studio but want to carry out this process in TFS 2015. Can you please tell me the process?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What type of application are you deploying? What have you read so far?

Comment: @jessehouwing I have read articles on the Internet. I am trying to deploy a desktop application. Not getting any valid links or references. Can you please guide me on this?

Comment: What kind of deployment? Wix? Clickonce? Custom installer? You really need to explain more.

Comment: @jessehouwing It is a Silverlight application. TFS release management is a new concept for me. So I just want to know just process of deployment from TFS.

Comment: @Neo4juser deploying a Silverlight app means updating the package file in the web application that is used to distribute, in other words you have to search for information regarding web site deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through [this website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/overview): Set up release definitions that represent your environments from development to production. Run automations to deploy your app to each environment. Add approvers to sign off that the app has been successfully deployed in an environment. Create your release manually or automatically from a build. Then track your releases as they are deployed to various environments.

And Get started with Release Management from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/getting-started/understand-rm